# Google Play Games Service TBM: Finished games keep showing up in list of matches

Tags: google-play-games

According to documentation, turn based matches should no longer show up in list of matches once all players (in addition to the finishing player) acknowledged the completion. However, matches keep showing up in state "Completed" even with all participants in state "Finished". Does this maybe only happen once productive, but stay in the list during development?

Comment: This maybe explained by the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer#match_states) that states "**COMPLETE** - *Indicates that a match has been played to completion (for example, a player has won the match)*. ***Once a player signals that the game is finished, Google Play games services sends a notification to all match participants to inform them that the match is over***. *Players have a chance to save their final game data but may not modify the game state further*."

Comment: Once in state "Complete" after first player finished a match, the other participants need to call "acknowledge" to signal they saw the result. After that, all participants are in state "Finished" and there is nothing else you can do with the match (other than maybe view the last state again depending on your game). According to the documentation, the match should no longer show up for a player in his Inbox, however right now it seems you have to explicitly dismiss such a game (maybe it expires after two weeks, haven't waited so long yet ;-)